# Difference in precision for Double in Release mode/Debug Mode

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, double, release, visual-studio-debugging

I am getting difference in the precision value after decimal point for Double processing in MSVC Release mode and Debug Mode .

Ex - 
Note:- Double dataFilled;
1) log(dataFilled)     ==> #include

```
 Debug Mode   dataFilled =96.1588665998339850
 Release Mode dataFilled =96.1588665998339420

 Intended value is 96.1588665998339850
```

Can can somebody please guide me why I am getting different values in Release and Debug.

Comment: It would help if you [provided code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Could be because release and debug mode uses different allocators?

Answer (score 1):

The IEEE binary representation of double-precision floating point numbers is good for only 15 full decimal digits.  You are printing 18.  It looks like the two results differ by the value of the least-significant mantissa bit (of 53).  Such a difference can easily arise from differences in the order of operations or handling of intermediate results between the two build configurations.

If you really need as much precision as you are asking for then you'll have to look into an arbitrary-precision math library.  Else, accept that your machine's native floating-point arithmetic is imprecise (as all machines' must be).  It can be a lot of work to perform extreme-precision arithmetic on a computer.

As a work around, VS may have build options you can set to make its floating-point handling in a Release build more like in a Debug build (likely for a small performance penalty).  But using such an option would just be a bandaid.  You really ought to use a computational approach that you can rely upon for the precision you need without any tricks.

Comment: And if this is about automated testing, then in most cases it is wrong to test for exact values of floating-point computations.  You should instead test that the result of the computation is within an acceptable delta of the expected value.